# Do scipy.sparse functions release the GIL?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, gil

#### Question

Do scipy.sparse functions, like `csr._mul_matvec` release the GIL?

#### Context

Python functions that wrap foreign code (like C) often release the GIL during execution, enabling parallelism with multi-threading.  This is common in the `numpy` codebase.  Is it also common in `scipy.sparse`?  If so which operations release the GIL?  If they don't release the GIL then is there a fundamental issue here why not or is it just lack of man-power?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. The macros releasing the GIL in numpy C code are typically of the form `NPY_BEGIN_THREADS_xxx`. Searching for `NPY_BEGIN_THREADS` in scipy's github repository [yields 6 hits](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=NPY_BEGIN_THREADS): 5 C files in the `ndimage` module, and a C++ file in the `sparsetools` submodule of the `sparse` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do, for Scipy versions >= 0.14.0

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer.  What was the reason?

Comment: Probably because it was very terse and offers no proof of this fact.